# preg_replace bbcode with quotes inside does not work

Tags: preg-replace

I tried to make a code hide tag for and its working when i write [hide]text[/hide] but not working when I`m write [hide="."]text[/hide]. here is my code:

```
 #\[hide](.*)\[\/hide\]#siU
```

when I change the code for this line -

```
 #\[hide=(.*)](.*)\[\/hide\]#siU
```

it not working for me. 
can anyone tell me whats is the problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first `.*` non greedy: `.*?`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first `.*` to a more specific expression. If quotes are necessary in your markup you could write

```
#\[hide="([^"]*)"](.*)\[\/hide\]#siU
```

or if not

```
#\[hide=([^\]])*](.*)\[\/hide\]#siU
```

To make your first version working togeher with your second but some brackets around the additional part with a following `?`:

```
#\[hide(="([^"]*)")?](.*)\[\/hide\]#siU
```